# CodeCompletion в IntellijIDEA 12.1..4

Tags: intellij-idea

У меня не работает CodeCompletion в файлах *.css. Работаю в ней всего 3-й день, а в настройках еще пока не разобрался как сделать, чтобы по Ctrl+Space появлялись подсказки именно в фале* .css. Нужно плагин скачивать (если да, то какой) или это в стандартных настройках есть? И еще, чтобы "тэги" в тех же CSS подсвечивались... '(

Answer (score 1):

CSS поддерживается только в версии Ultimate Edition.

[Пруфлинк](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

Comment: это точно? я так и догадывался =( спасибо